# asp.net mvc3 site loading too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My site writen in ASP.NET MVC3, using Subsonic and have around 30k record in database. I have cached all database. Basic i have a function similar this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateItem(string json, string key)
{
    if(Setting.Get("SafeMode").To<bool>()) return;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    var model = ntwgObject.ntwgSerialization.JsonDeserialize<Model.ProductResult>(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(json));
    Product p = Product.Get(model.Id);//This method get product by id
    if (p == null)
    {
      p = new Product(){ Name = ".."};
    }
    p.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now
    p.Save();
}
```

I have a software that i have used `HttpWebRequest` to post data to UpdateItem controller above. Have around 1 - 2 request per second. But the site loading too slow. If i open `"SafeMode"` `(Setting.Get("SafeMode").To<bool>() = True)` Then the site loading fast.

This is weird. I wonder if the site loading slow when have few request via `HttpWebRequest` object? For some reason that i have used GC.Collect() method. Maybe this is problem also ?

Comment: You are saying that when you set "SafeMode" to true, the site loads fast?  It sounds like you have your answer.  Find out what uses that setting and profile what it does.

Comment: Yep, when i set "SafeMode" to true the site loads fast. i just updated fully code. please review it

Comment: How many times are you calling this per request? (I'm just going to ignore the manual GC that you are doing twice which is not so cool)

Comment: Hi Luke, im agreeing with you for GC. What o you mean for calling this? You mean how many requests per second?

Comment: I think i have found my problem. When more request send to the site, the function to get Product by id (Product p = Product.Get(model.Id)). My database cached as a list, (Cache = List<Product>()). I just need improve this point then my site working fine and fast.

Comment: That may solve your bottleneck but the use of GC.Collect and Gc.WaitForPendingFinalizers is both weird and unnecessary - would be curious to know why you're calling them in the first place (and also why twice).